# How to configure wysiwyg_tools_plus module?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Has anyone used this module ([wysiwyg_tools_plus](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_tools_plus))?  It give ckeditor the ability to create tabs & accordion effects via a wysiwyg ([sample video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttjaoBhsycU)).  The [docs on usage](http://geoffmaxey.com/content/wysiwyg-tools-plus-user-guide) look good, but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to actually get the icons to show up in ckeditor.

I've done this:

- installed ckeditor module & verified usage
- installed/enabled wysiwyg_tools_plus
- set ckeditor as the editor for my text formats
- tried to edit profiles (/admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/full_html/edit), but haven't found a way to add the Tab or Accordion buttons

Any idea what I need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways of running CKEditor in Drupal, as a straight module install, and as a component of the WYSIWYG Tools module. It's the latter that you need.

So, install the normal WYSIWYG Tools module and then follow the instructions to install an editor (CKEditor) within. I've found only < v4 seems to work for this unfortunately, but there is an update to v3 from 2013 which seems to work ok.

Once you've got that working you will get a WYSIWYG editor that has no buttons, it's not broken, it just doesn't tell you that you have to configure it for each view (full HTML / filtered HTML etc) and select the buttons you want to appear.

When choosing the buttons, near the bottom there's a few for accordion & tabs, so just make sure these are selected for the content types you want to use.

It's not exactly intuitive, but it's actually fairly easy when you know how!

Hope that helps.